# how to get ContactsLaunchActivity in android?

Tags: android

create a new AVD (2.1) version. start it. and now, click to contacts icon --  you will get similar kinda screen as described below.
Now my requirement is to catch up with the **same screen and flow of android functions** after certain click event on a button. 
**How to get that screen??**

**Phone  Call-Logs Contacts Favorites**
you dont have any contacts to display
(if you just added an account it will
take few minutes to sync contacts)

- To add contact press menu and touch
- Display options

Answer (score 0):

Later i found that it can be implemented using the code given below :)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);             
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.contacts","com.android.contacts.DialtactsContactsEntryActivity" ));              
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please format you code. Just edit your answer, select the code, and click on the {} button in the editor toolbar.